# Проблема с webapp в aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

Проблема с телеграмм ботом, использую кнопку с браузером (webapp). Пытаюсь перенаправить сообщение с ней в другой канал, выдает ошибку `aiogram.utils.exceptions.BadRequest: Button_type_invalid.`
Если убрать `web_app=WebAppInfo(url="ссылка")` и вместо него поставить просто `url="ссылка"` все будет хорошо.

````
async def button_4(message: types.Message):

    channel = 'id канала'

    markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    button = InlineKeyboardButton(text="Текст кнопки", web_app=WebAppInfo(url="ссылка"))
    markup.add(button)

    await bot.send_message(channel, text="Текст сообщения", reply_markup=markup)```
````

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, вы используете aiogram версии 2 и выше, но не 3. В aiogram 2 в InlineKeyboardButton не поддерживается web_app, к сожалению :(

Документация для aiogram 2 (не поддерживается web_app): https://aiogram-birdi7.readthedocs.io/en/latest/telegram/types/inline_keyboard.html#inlinekeyboardbutton

Документация для aiogram 3.4.0 (поддерживается web_app): https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/api/types/inline_keyboard_button.html#aiogram.types.inline_keyboard_button.InlineKeyboardButton

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте Вашу версию aiogram.
Я не нашел информации с какой именно версии добавили web_app, но могу с увереностью сказать, что на версии 2.25.1 - работает.

https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/v2.25.1/telegram/types/inline_keyboard.html?highlight=InlineKeyboardButton#inlinekeyboardbutton

Comment: просто так, к слову: может, это только меня смущает, когда дают совет типа «проверьте версию/файл/ещё чего-нибудь». вот как её проверять-то? как в анекдоте ведь получается: петька, проверь приборы! - 150! - что 150? - а что приборы?